# How we can change the existing Window Membership Provider to Claims Based Authentication in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: claims-based-auth, membership-provider

Will any one help me to tell how we can change the existing Membership Provider to claims based authentication.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

[Migrate from classic-mode to claims-based authentication (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251985.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't feel comfortable, or don't understand, Powershell, you can also visit this location:  Central Administration > Security > Specify Authentication Providers.

1. Click the name of the zone ("Default" if your web app wasn't added to a different zone).
2. You can add check marks to the boxes for "Enable Windows Authentication" and "Enable Forms Based Authentication".
3. Custom sign-in pages can be designated here as well.